# How to enable/disable editing in a view based NSTableView using bindings?

Tags: cocoa, binding, nstableview, nstextfield

I cannot figure a way to enable/disable editing in view based NSTableViews using cocoa bindings.
I mean, I can perfectly enable/disable editing in a *separate* NSTextField, by binding it's "editable" attribute to a file's owner property such as

```
@property BOOL canModify;
```

(bind to: file's owner)
(Model Key Path: self.canModify)

But if I do exactly the same with a NSTextField in a view based TableView the binding seems to be totally ignored.
Also to be noticed that I can populate the table via bindings/array controllers so it's quite strange that the stuff doesn't work only for the "editable" property.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's no problem in Apple's implementation of File's owner bindings for tablecellviews. I simply overlooked an IB warning.
"... Objects inside view-based cells may only be connected to the tableview's delegate."
I did set the "delegate" outlet of the TableView to my WindowController (implementing the "delegate protocol) and everything is working fine, without any double double double passages over table Cell's objectValues.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your property and the key path of your binding don't match, although maybe that's just a typo: `canModify` vs. `canModyfy` ("i" vs. "y").

The `editable` binding should work just fine. You should check your other bindings, such as the `value` binding, to see if it has the Conditionally Sets Editable binding option enabled. Annoyingly, this option is enabled by default.

Lastly, you haven't explained in which NIB you're defining your cell views. Are they defined in the same NIB as the table view itself, or are they in a separate NIB? That would affect which object is File's Owner.

Even when table cell views are defined inside the same NIB as the table view, I believe they are encoded as a NIB-within-a-NIB. That is, each table cell view subhierarchy is actually encoded into a NIB blob and that NIB blob is archived into the parent NIB. When the table cell view sub-NIB is loaded, the table view's delegate is usually supplied as its owner. So, binding to File's Owner may not have the effect you expect.

For table cell views, you usually bind the subviews (like an `NSTextField`) to the table cell view itself, keyed off of the `objectValue` property.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of the typo (you're right, it was simply a typo) and thank you for remembering me of the conditionally set editable's flag. I completely looked over it, but it didn't solve the problem.
Actually i have two tableview. The first one is in the App's main Window for which i've bound my Editable flag to the App Delegate object. The second tableview is in a separate window where i use "file's owner" to set the binding. Well, actually i can see no difference in behaviour, not even with the "conditionally sets editable" flag unchecked.

Comment: As i've said, my content and data bindings are working fine. Granted: they refer to an array controller object in the xib (by the way: i'm using XCode 6 so i don't edit Nib's directly but Xib's) and i also tried defining a object controller and setting the "editable" binding realtive to it but with no luck. So i don't think it's a problem with sub-nib.
I suspect that there's some difference between cell-base and view based table-views.

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that the problem is only "view based" tableviews related. 
I've created a dummy cell-based tableview and the Editable binding is working fine, both in the App Delegate scenario and in the File's owner one.

Comment: I use the `editable` binding in view-based table views and it works just fine. I believe the difference is in what you're binding to. I think you have to bind to the table cell view or something within it but I admit I'm not sure. Try using a custom subclass of `NSTableCellView` with a `controller` property. When vending the cell view from `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`, set the `controller` property to your controller. Then, bind the text field's `editable` binding to the cell view, through its `controller` property to the property on the controller which should control editing.

Comment: What do you usually bind your "Editable" binding to? 
I mean, which values do you use for "bind to" and "Model Key Path" in your NSTableCellView bindings tab?

Comment: I bind to the table cell view which contains the text field, with model key path "objectValue.myPropertyWhichControlsEditability". In my case, the editability is a property of each object. It sounds like, in your case, it's the same for all rows. Still, I suggest trying to bind through the table cell view. Of course, you should double-check the basics, too. Are all of the properties in your key path KVO-compliant?

Comment: Bingo, Ken.
I've played a bit with my model's class. I added a dummy "Editable" boolean flag to my model and bound it to the "editable" binding through the table cell view's object value.
And it worked! 
Apple did a great job allowing editing on a cell by cell basis, but i fear they got out of touch with simpler situations (like mine) where i'd be just fine simply enabling/disabling editing on a column basis. Apparently the only working binding is thru table cell views, the other ones, though being "syntactically" allowed (no compiler error), simply don't work.

Comment: Anyway, thank you. You did put my on the right track!